# Безопасно ли обновлять php с release 3.e16_1.3 на release 23.e16_4

Tags: php

Хочу установить один из модулей php, он по зависимостям предлагает обновить еще пачку модулей, включая сам php. Обновление идет не до версии, а только release. Я понятия не имею, что в php означает релиз и беспокоюсь за свой самописный проект, который работает на данном сервере - что могло измениться в этом релизе?

Собственно вот:

```
# yum info phpInstalled PackagesName        : phpArch        : x86_64Version     : 5.3.3Release     : 3.el6_1.3Size        : 3.5 MRepo        : installedFrom repo   : crSummary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sitesURL         : http://www.php.net/License     : PHPDescription : PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it            : easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages. PHP also            : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and            : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a            : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common            : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.            :            : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP            : language to Apache HTTP Server.Available PackagesName        : phpArch        : x86_64Version     : 5.3.3Release     : 23.el6_4Size        : 1.1 MRepo        : updatesSummary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sitesURL         : http://www.php.net/License     : PHPDescription : PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it            : easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages. PHP also            : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and            : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a            : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common            : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.            :            : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP            : language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Поставьте, не взлетит, откатитесь.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае безопаснее не обновлением, а снести старый и поставить новый. Но только не через "purge", чтобы конфиги сохранились! Возможно, придётся подправить конфиги, если там что-то поменяли.